# executing function/method in button click event

Tags: c#, sql-server, function

I have this collection as seen in the code below and I am trying to execute the InserData function to insert the data form the collection to my SQL DB table in the Button_Click_1 event and cannot make it work. Any help?

The code takes data from form fields and adds to the Collection. Once the addition is complete and the user is done adding I want the entire collection written to a SQL data table.

```
   public class LotData
    {
        public string Lot;
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int PO { get; set; }
        public string MfgPart { get; set; }
    }

    // code to add from control data to list

    ObservableCollection<LotData> lot = new ObservableCollection<LotData>();

    private ObservableCollection<LotData> LoadCollectionData()
    {
        // List<LotData> lot = new List<LotData>();
        lot.Add(new LotData()
        {
            Lot = LotNo.Text,
            Description = frmDescription.Text,
            PO = int.Parse(frmPO.Text),
            MfgPart = frmMfgPart.Text,
        });
        return lot;
    }

    //button to add list data to datagrid on form
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gridLotData.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData();

        LotNo.Text = String.Empty;
        frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
        frmDescription.Text = String.Empty;
        frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
        frmPO.Text = string.Empty;
    }



    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //send data from DataGrid to database
    {         
                InserData(LotData);
    }

    public void InserData(LotData lot)
    {

        string strConn = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Matthew\\QCast.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into LotData Values (@LotNum)";
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LotNum", lot.Lot);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific then "does not work". What is happening or not happening? Any exception? If so please note the line they happen on, the type, message and ideally the stack trace.

Comment: What have you tried and what were the error message(s)? There is a lot of code here, so it might help to narrow it down with a relevant error message that we can use to help you find a solution.

Comment: It sounds like you want to call InsertData() from Button_Click_1. Please be more specific about what's stopping you from doing just that. You're calling methods all over, so it seems as if you know how to do that. Are you having trouble getting ahold of some particular `LotData` instance? (Also: Why is `lot` a field instead of a local variable in `LoadCollectionData()`?)

Comment: I want to run  public void InserData inside the Button_Click_1 and the code will not run - LotScan.LotData is a type which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: "I want to run public void InserData inside the Button_Click_1 and the code will not run"  -- what do you mean, will not run? Are you saying the code inside the Button_Click_1 event never gets hit?  Or are you saying the event gets hit, but then the InsertData() function fails afterwards?  This is why its *very helpful* to actually post the error message/stack trace that VS gives you.

Comment: @Matthew Show us what you tried. What you have now is nothing. Button_Click_1 is empty. You have one part of your code that won't compile, and that's the one part you didn't show us.

Comment: Error CS0119 It won't even compile. I think I'm not declaring it properly. But I don't know how to declare it differently

Comment: I declared it this way inside the Button_Click_1   InserData(LotData);

Comment: @Matthew Please edit your question so the code is in your question. Now: Do you have any instance of LotData anywhere that you want to add to your database? Do you understand the difference between a class and an *instance* of a class? For example, do you understand the difference between the class `String`, and the string "hello"? If you want to print "hello", do you call `Console.WriteLine(String)` and hope that the compiler will guess which string you want, or do you call `Console.WriteLine("hello")`?

Comment: I want to add all the items in the ObservableCollection<LotData> to the SQL db table. Sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a few things in the wrong place and you're recreating the ObservableCollection.  You need to iterate over this to add all items to the DB:

```
private const string strConn = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Matthew\\QCast.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
private ObservableCollection<LotData> lot = new ObservableCollection<LotData>();

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Bind ItemsSource once
    gridLotData.ItemsSource = lot;
}

public void AddDataToGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Read data from form and add to collection
    lot.Add(new LotData()
    {
        Lot = LotNo.Text,
        Description = frmDescription.Text,
        PO = int.Parse(frmPO.Text),
        MfgPart = frmMfgPart.Text,
    });

    // Clear entry fields
    LotNo.Text = String.Empty;
    frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
    frmDescription.Text = String.Empty;
    frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
    frmPO.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void WriteCollectionToDb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            foreach (var lotData in lot)
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT into LotData Values (@LotNum)", conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LotNum", lotData.Lot);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: finally someone who can deal with my stupidity! Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

In InserData, you have to iterate through all the items in the collection and then insert into DB